# How to pull a list of values from a JSON string and iterate through them?

Tags: javascript, json

I have a dynamic JSON map of countries to states. ex. `{"Canada":["Ontario","Quebec","Alberta"],"USA":["Michigan","Maine","New Hampshire"]}`

I know the selected country name.

QUESTION: How do I get the list of states for the selected country name out of the map and iterate through the values?

```
<script>
function onChangeCountry() {
    var selectedCountry = $('#country').find(":selected").text();
    alert("010 selectedCountry = "+ selectedCountry); // <<-- this gets me the selected country, works fine

    var jsonMapCountryToStates = ${jsonMapCountryToStates};
    alert("020 JSON.stringify(jsonMapCountryToStates) = "+JSON.stringify(jsonMapCountryToStates)); // <-- this shows me the whole map

    // how do I iterate through the list of states for 'selectedCountry' ?
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make an array of them perhaps, then it is like every other array.

```js
let fundata = {"Canada":["Ontario","Quebec","Alberta"],"USA":["Michigan","Maine","New Hampshire"]};

console.log(Array.from(fundata.USA));

// or using the other syntax:
let namedPlace = "USA";
console.log(Array.from(fundata[namedPlace]));
```

A little more action in an example:

```js
var fundata = {
  "Canada": ["Ontario", "Quebec", "Alberta"],
  "USA": ["Michigan", "Maine", "New Hampshire"]
};


function onChangeCountry(e) {
  let selectedCountry = $(this).find(":selected").val();
  console.log("010 selectedCountry = " + selectedCountry);
  fundata[selectedCountry].forEach(element => console.log("State:", element));
}
for (const prop in fundata) {
  $('#country').append("<option value='" + `${prop}` + "'>" + `${prop}` + "</option>")
  console.log(`${prop}: ${fundata[prop]}`);
}

$("#country").on("change", onChangeCountry);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="country" />
```

Comment: Also could use `const states = [...fundata[namePlaced]`

Comment: Thanks!  Worked.  In the end it looked like this: `var arrStates = Array.from(jsonMapCountryToStates[selectedCountry]);  for (var i = 0; i < arrStates.length; i++) {  var state = arrTableNames[I];  alert("state = "+state); }`